# For loop isn't working well inside a thread

Tags: java, android, arrays, multithreading, boolean

**EDIT2:** Here's the code and output:

```
private void myFunc()
{
    itemsIdsArray = new boolean[3];
    for(int i = 0;i<itemsIdsArray.length;i++){
        itemsIdsArray[i] = true;
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<itemsIdsArray.length;i++){
        if(itemsIdsArray[i]){
            Log.d(Global.TAG,"first in i: " + i);
        }
    }

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                for(int i = 0;i<itemsIdsArray.length;i++){
                    if(itemsIdsArray[i]){
                        Log.d(Global.TAG,"second in i: " + i);
                    }
                }
            }finally{

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

output:

```
08-15 03:27:38.136: D/MyTag(22229): first in i: 0
08-15 03:27:38.136: D/MyTag(22229): first in i: 1
08-15 03:27:38.136: D/MyTag(22229): first in i: 2
```

My question: Why the second loop i's are not printed.?

Comment: How does `itemsIdsArray` get initialized?

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: You need to show us more code. For all we know you just set every element of `itemsIdsArray` to `false` and this is doing exactly what it should be doing.

Comment: itemsIdsArray is just a field, The cells of that array are filled with true dynamically, it's alot of code, I don't think I should post it. I'm editing the original post within 1 minute.

Comment: @idish don't post *everything*, only what's relevant to `itemsIdsArray`initialization, and whatever connects the method where that happens with the method where the `timer` `Thread` is initialized and run. Your edit is a replica of the code you posted first. That's not going to help.

Comment: @Mena Pretty sure you'll understand now.

Comment: Show us the declaration of `itemsIdsArray` as well; also show us all the places you call `myFunc()` from. This is like pulling teeth.

Comment: @JasonC  boolean[] itemsIdsArray; It's just a field in my class. That's it.  myFunc() is being called from onClick button event

Comment: Also add some logging info in the thread but outside that loop. Is it possible that `Log.d()` is not thread-safe?

Comment: @JasonC It's not possible since also other functions are not being called inside that if statement. and I have even printed the array inside the thread, it's all false.

Comment: Is `myFunc()` being called twice, or anything else that could modify the values in `itemsIdsArray` before the thread is finished?

Comment: @JasonC Outside the loop it's just works fine. The only problem is inside the if statement.

Comment: @JasonC Sorry @ my language, I was stuck at that problem too much time. You were totally right. There's another function being called instantly after myFunc() which resets that array.

Comment: @JasonC If you could post that as an answer, I will accept it, thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myFunc()` is being called twice, or if anything else is modifying the values in `itemsIdsArray` before the thread is finished, then that would affect what the thread sees.

If you want the effect to be like a "snapshot" of what the values were when the thread is started, copy the relevant arrays before creating the thread, and pass the local copies to the thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, you are totally right and I haven't thought of that the array is re-initialized by the foreground thread while the background thread executes. I managed to fix it and it works just fine now :)